# Scikit-Learn Classification and Regression with Weights

Tags: python, classification, regression, scikit-learn

How can I do classification or regression in sklearn if I want to weight each sample differently? Is there a way to do it with a custom loss function? If so, what does that loss function look like in general? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To weigh individual samples, feed a `sample_weight` array to the estimator's `fit` method. This should be a 1-d array of length `n_samples` (i.e. the same dimension as `y` in most tasks):

```
estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight=some_array)
```

Not all models support this, check the documentation.