# Lasso Regression with weighted input in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, scikit-learn, orange

I am interested in doing Lasso Regression technique in Python. However, I would like to weight the input data for the algorithm.
Can you suggest some libraries that can perform the Lasso regression taking into consideration the input weights?

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265512/scikit-learn-classification-and-regression-with-weights) that `scikit-learn` provides weighted Ridge regression, but not weighted Lasso regression.

Comment: So that your question does not rely on the one you've linked to could you explain the problem and what you've tried so far. Check out how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#lasso) for info on scikit-learn lasso